# Meteor, Mongo DB data insert error

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I learning meteor 1.4 with this [TUTORIAL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87itlujo8u0&index=6&list=PLLnpHn493BHGaNQgSl1lppoNrpjlr24z5)
trying to insert data through CMD with this command

```
db.tasks.insert({ itemOne: { text:'hello', value:0}}, itemTwo: {text:'hi', value:0}});
```

but get this error:

```
E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list @(shell):1:61
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.tasks.insert({ itemOne: { text:'hello', value:0}, itemTwo: { text:'hi', value:0}});
```

Now it should work, this inser a record like this:

```
{
  itemOne: { text:'hello', value:0},
  itemTwo: { text:'hi', value:0}
}
```

Comment: I am using CMD to insert data

Comment: Thanks for help, I updated the question have a look tut I am following, in tut after enter command new mongo DB cmd open, I try ur command it show msg WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
meteor:PRIMARY>, didn;t open new mongo CMD

Comment: that is video editing... if you pause after he hit return key, you will see the error in console. WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 }) it's correct it means that you have insert 1 record.